# I want to remove the Disclosure Icon from List items on SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am setting a List and make Navigation Link and it automatically adds Disclosure Icon that I do not want. I couldn't remove it.

I tried ScrollView it solves but also has Memory Leak because it doesn't have Reuse.

```swift
List {
    ForEach(recipeData) { recipe in
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(recipe: recipe)) {
            RecipeCard(recipe: recipe)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .shadow(radius: 10)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately at the moment there's no standard way to do this (I mean, you can't customise your `NavigationLink` appearance). There's a workaround, though:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<3) { _ in
                    HStack {
                        Text("Hello World")
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination View")) {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```